# Stack divs vertically & keep 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

I want to have two stacked `div`s on one side, and then have a single column on the other side with the same `height` as the left `div`s.

Kind of like this:

[image: SS]

I have the two `div`s and a side bar, but the two `div`s won't stack.

Here is what I have so far [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kryometric/y71tkmtw/)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen);
 body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.description h1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.description,
.sidebar,
.demo-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.description {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: "Oxygen";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #eee;
  width: 15%;
  height: 575px;
}
.demo-container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: "Oxygen";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class="demo-container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium lorem nec tortor elementum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium lorem nec tortor elementum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just did a bit of improve in the answer if you wanna take a look, by not forcing to have the left columns always 50%. but keeping the same  height

Comment: @dippas Am I not supposed to be able to adjust the width of the sidebar?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? this is a flexible layout the sidebar will adjust by itself the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are complicating a lot, here is a basic demo of what you want using `flexbox`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%
}
.fl {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 5px;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black
}
.flex-item:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin: 10px 0 0
}
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="fl">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium lorem nec tortor elementum, et aliquam erat feugiat. Duis interdum enim vitae justo cursus pulvinar eu ac nulla. Donec consectetur vehicula turpis. Nunc laoreet tincidunt elit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium lorem nec tortor elementum, et aliquam erat feugiat. Duis interdum enim vitae justo cursus pulvinar eu ac nulla. Donec consectetur vehicula turpis. Nunc laoreet tincidunt elit
        ultrices elementum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur augue magna, posuere id tortor vel, condimentum consectetur lacus. Pellentesque dui est, ornare vitae semper et, dapibus ut lacus.
        Etiam sed porta dui. Phasellus non nisl eget dolor commodo imperdiet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fl sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OCD people everywhere are very upset with how that looks. The tops don't line up, nor do the bottoms, yet they're both clearly covering the same area.

Comment: OCD people can rest, that is fixed now in my updated answer

Comment: I'd suggest using `:nth-child(n+2)` instead of `:not(:first-child)` instead of `:not(:first-of-type)`, but that works too. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'd really suggest not using `:not(:first-of-type)`... Many people will read `.cls:not(:first-of-type)` as excluding the first ocurance of `.cls` per scope. *This is not what that does.* That excludes the first occurrence of any _tag_, and only applies if it also matches `.cls`. EX: `<hr /><hr />`, `<hr class="cls" /><hr />`, and `<div /><hr class="cls" />` will all have zero matches. Sadly there is no `:nth-of-class()`

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<div class="sidebar"></div>` before the other two divs, then float them all right. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y71tkmtw/1/

```
  .description,
  .sidebar, .demo-container {
    float: right;
    margin: 40px;
  }
```

Comment: I'd have gone with `float:left` on the non-sidebars and `right` on the sidebar, but that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `<div>` surrounding the 2 divs on the left-hand side, with float:left. Add float:right to the sidebar.

```
      .left-container
      {
        width: 85%;
        float:left;

      }      
      .sidebar {
        background: #eee;
        width: 15%;
        height: 575px;
        float:right;
      }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dncgytef/2/

Comment: Is there a way to center all the stuff in the parent div of everything?   Like the left-container will be centered alongside the sidebar.

Comment: @user5544792 have you seen my answer?